# fabric pass arguments to roledefs

Tags: python, fabric

I know using fabric, you can pass arguments to fabric task like:

```
def task(something=''):
    print "You said %s" % something

fab task:something='hello'
```

what if I want to pass some arguments to roledefs. Here is my example:

```
env.roledefs = {
    'node1':          ['node1.%s' % DOMAIN],
    'node2':          ['node2.%s' % DOMAIN]
}
```

Is there anyway I can pass in the DOMAIN by running something like:

```
fab task -argument='mydomain.com' (pseudo code)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a custom env variable via [--set](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/usage/fab.html#cmdoption--set) cmd option:

```
fabric task --set domain='mydomain.com'
```

Then in fabfile, just read from `env.domain`:

```
env.roledefs = {
    'node1':          ['node1.%s' % env.domain],
    'node2':          ['node2.%s' % env.domain]
}
```

Hope that helps you.